# Can't show data in javascript console

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have a registration form in my Laravel project. I submit that registration form data to laravel controller using ajax from javascript. After successfully stored those registration data in database I return the `insertedID` from controller to javascript and use `console.log()` function to show that `id`. In my javascript, `console.log()` shows that `id` and auto disappear after half mili second. But I don't want it to disappear.

**Here is my js code**

```
var name = $('#reg_name').val(); //reg_name is the id of the input field
var email = $('#reg_email').val(); //reg_email is the id of the input field
$.get( 'signup', {'name': name, 'email': email,'_token':$('input[name=_token]').val()}, function( data )
{
  //Here 'signup' is my route name

  console.log(data);
});
```

**Here is my controller function**

```
public function signup(RegistrationFormValidation $request)
{
    $data = new User();

    $data->name = $request->name;
    $data->email = $request->email;

    $data->save();

    $lastInsertedId = $data->id;

    if($lastInsertedId > 0)
    {
        return $lastInsertedId;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Here I concise my code.

What's the problem in my javascript ?

Comment: Are you seeing any errors?

Comment: no errors showing

Comment: You're submitting a form, and your server responses with a new page?

Comment: If you want to return anything from php to javascript, you need to print or echo it out. Returning it from your php controller probably does not generate any output from your script.

Comment: @jeroen...That's a point. But nothing changed. still disappear after changing that

Comment: You not printing anything from the controller, try `echo json_encode($lastinserId);` instead of return

Comment: How do you submit your registration form? Are you preventing the default redirect? If not, the browser does a new request and the console is being cleared out.

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile ... U told about the sending process but that's not solve the problem

Comment: @Teemu...exactly...while the `id` disappear...the page also auto reload

Comment: @MaKobi.....Yes the page auto relaod and the `id` disappear. How to to prevent default redirect ?

Comment: Who knows, you haven't shown the code calling the code in the exsample. Usually you do `event.preventDefault()`, bvut that depends on the real code you have.

Answer (score 2):

If you are loading a new page, the default behaviour of the Chrome Dev Tools is to clear the logs. You can enable the `Preserve log` checkbox at the top of the console to prevent this behaviour.

In other situations, the data emitted to the console is modified after the logging to reflect subsequent updates. To prevent this, one can log a JSON serialized version of the data:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
```

(but probably this is not your case).